# When I switch between nested routes (subroutes) using 'Link' , parent component unmounts. Is there any way to avoid this?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

> Updated: This code has problem. I have answered below

This is my outer 'App' component. In this I have a 'Dashboard' component route

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="*" component={() => <h1>not found</h1>} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

'Dashboard' component containing nested routes to 'Home' and 'Chat' component

```
function Dashboard({ match }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("dashboard mounted");
    return () => console.log("dashboard unmounted");
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={Home} />
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}/chat`} component={Chat} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

'Home' and 'Chat' component

```
function Home({ match }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("home mounted");
    return () => console.log("home unmounted");
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>home component</h3>
      <Link to={`${match.url}/chat`}>
        <button>chat</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

function Chat() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("chat mounted");
    return () => console.log("chat unmounted");
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Chat component</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is when I navigate from 'Home' to 'Chat', 'Dashboard' (parent) component unmounts. I want to avoid this

[codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-issues-yj0bp?file=/src/example.js)

check console

Comment: And why exactly do you want to avoid unmounting the `Dashboard` component? `react-router-dom` works in that way, so if you're making it deviate from its proper functionality, it could introduce unexpected behavior. What exactly are you trying to achieve, could you tell us more? There probably is another way to solve your issue

Comment: Hi @Kapobajza, but if we have deeply nested route architecture and I just want to go to nested route at same level, then it will cause performance issues as the whole tree structure will be reloaded. I think in Angular we can switch between nested components without reloading parent component

Comment: Hi @Kapobajza, Actually I want to fetch common data in 'Dashboard' component to be used by nested components and add add socket event listeners in my 'Dashboard' component. At the same time keep my 'App' component minimal. can you help ?

Comment: Do you have to fetch it in the `Dashboard` component? Couldn't you just fetch that common data in the `App` component?

Comment: It is good to keep logic outside 'App'. Also my code has problem. React router does not unmount parent component (Dashboard). I have answered below.

Answer (score 1):

My above code has problem. Actually React router doesn't unmount parent component if there are nested routes and we switch between them. . I forgot to add empty dependence array in 'Dashboard', 'Home' and 'Chat'. Now there is now console message showing 'dashboard unmounted'.

> From react docs: 
> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest diffrent `<Switch />` tags.

```
export default function App() {

useEffect(() => {
   console.log("app mounted");
   return () => console.log("app unmounted");
});

return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <hr />

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/dashboard/chat" component={Chat} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Home} />
        <Route path="*" component={() => <h1>not found</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand what you are trying to say. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Inside your ```Dashboard``` tag you have another ```<Switch />``` and the router cannot handle multiple nested Switch tags. So if you want to keep your parent state without unmounting it you have to remove the nested Switch tag. This snipped use just one Switch to handle all routes and prevent the parent unmounting

Comment: but even if I remove nested <Switch/> tags, 'Dashboard' component unmounts.